# MVVM - Bind JSON Child Elements To Kendo UI Controls

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

i want to bind child nodes to two different kendo ui controls , but my Kendo Data source fetches the data from service in single call ,

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable {
 dataSource : new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/data/auras',
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET',
        }
    },
    schema: {
      /////////
    },   
 });
}
```

My JSON response result looks like this

```
[
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters": {
        "batter": [
            {
                "id": "1001",
                "type": "Regular"
            },
            {
                "id": "1002",
                "type": "Chocolate"
            },
            {
                "id": "1003",
                "type": "Blueberry"
            },
            {
                "id": "1004",
                "type": "Devil's Food"
            }
        ]
    },
    "topping": [
        {
            "id": "5001",
            "type": "None"
        },
        {
            "id": "5002",
            "type": "Glazed"
        },
        {
            "id": "5005",
            "type": "Sugar"
        },
        {
            "id": "5007",
            "type": "Powdered Sugar"
        },
        {
            "id": "5006",
            "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles"
        },
        {
            "id": "5003",
            "type": "Chocolate"
        },
        {
            "id": "5004",
            "type": "Maple"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Here I have to bind batter ( is child Element) to One Gridview && topping ( is child Element) to another Gridview ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [schema.parse](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) to split your JSON result into two lists. Something like:

```
var batters = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: []
});

var toppings = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: []
});

var allData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '/data/auras',
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET',
        }
    },
    schema: {
        parse: function (data) {
            batters.data(data[0].batters.batter);
            toppings.data(data[0].toppings);
            return data;
        }
    },   
 });

allData.fetch();

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    batters: batters,
    toppings: toppings
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , here i want put all my stuff inside the observable object .

Comment: The code could be rearranged to move things into the observable. I don't think that makes my answer wrong.

Comment: Hi, here i have another quetion ,is it possible to get <br>                          "type": "donut",
"name": "Cake",
"ppu": 0.55, <br/> from allData datasource